# Knockout custom binding for jQuery fadeIn fadeOut with observable object

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Using Knockout and jQuery, I want an edit panel to fade-in and fade-out. Knockout is calling the jQuery methods via the bindingHandlers facility. The fadeIn works ok, but the fadeOut is not. Here is the custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).toggle(ko.unwrap(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).fadeIn("slow") : $(element).fadeOut("slow");
  }
};
```

My HTML code displays a list of cities, and allows you to edit each city (which reveals an edit box). My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: cities">
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.editCity">edit</button>
  <br />
</div>
<br />

<div data-bind="fadeVisible: cityToEdit">
  <div data-bind="if: cityToEdit">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;">
      <h4>Edit Form</h4>
      <input data-bind="value: cityToEdit().name" />
      <br />
      <input data-bind="value: cityToEdit().population" />
      <br />
      <button data-bind="click: $root.cancelEdit">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you go into the fiddle, and click edit against any city, you'll see the edit panel fadeIn. So far, so good. The problem is when I fadeOut. I need the fadeOut to occur AND COMPLETE before the observable variable "cityToEdit" is cleared and the UI updates to reflect this.

https://jsfiddle.net/4qhkkeLh/50/

Is there any way I can achieve a fadeIn and fadeOut whilst keeping the data structure how it is? Hopefully I can just adjust the custom binding.

Is there a way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` binding removes the contents of the element you're attempting to fade out. You can fix this issue in several ways, depending on the kind of interaction you want to achieve.

### A view-only fix

Remove the `if` binding and clear inputs on cancel:

```
<input data-bind="value: (cityToEdit() || {}).name" />
<br />
<input data-bind="value: (cityToEdit() || {}).population" />
```

```js
var myVm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.cities = ko.observableArray(
    [{
        'name': 'London',
        'population': 1000000
      },
      {
        'name': 'Cardiff',
        'population': 250000
      }
    ]
  );
  self.cityToEdit = ko.observable(null);

  self.editCity = function() {
    self.cityToEdit(this);
  }

  self.cancelEdit = function() {
    self.cityToEdit(null);
  }
}


ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).toggle(ko.unwrap(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).fadeIn("slow") : $(element).fadeOut("slow");
  }
};


var vm = new myVm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: cities">
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.editCity">edit</button>
  <br />
</div>
<br />

<div data-bind="fadeVisible: cityToEdit">
  <div data-bind="">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;">
      <h4>Edit Form</h4>
      <input data-bind="value: (cityToEdit() || {}).name" />
      <br />
      <input data-bind="value: (cityToEdit() || {}).population" />
      <br />
      <button data-bind="click: $root.cancelEdit">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Downsides:

- Ugly data-binds
- Clears the values before fading which is a bit jumpy

### A better fix

Create a new property that controls visibility:

```
self.cityToEdit = ko.observable(null);
self.canEdit = ko.observable(false);
self.cityToEdit.subscribe(city => self.canEdit(true));

self.cancelEdit = function() {
  self.canEdit(false);
}
```

Bind to `canEdit` instead of `cityToEdit`:

```
 <div data-bind="fadeVisible: canEdit"> ... </div>
```

```js
var myVm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.cities = ko.observableArray(
    [{
        'name': 'London',
        'population': 1000000
      },
      {
        'name': 'Cardiff',
        'population': 250000
      }
    ]
  );
  self.cityToEdit = ko.observable(null);
  self.canEdit = ko.observable(false);
  self.cityToEdit.subscribe(city => self.canEdit(true));
  
  
  self.editCity = function() {
    self.cityToEdit(this);
  }

  self.cancelEdit = function() {
    self.canEdit(false);
  }
}


ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).toggle(ko.unwrap(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).fadeIn("slow") : $(element).fadeOut("slow");
  }
};


var vm = new myVm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: cities">
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.editCity">edit</button>
  <br />
</div>
<br />

<div data-bind="fadeVisible: canEdit">
  <div style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;">
    <h4>Edit Form</h4>
    <input data-bind="value: (cityToEdit() || {}).name" />
    <br />
    <input data-bind="value: (cityToEdit() || {}).population" />
    <br />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.cancelEdit">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Downsides:

- During the fade-out you can still edit the boxes
- You need an extra property

Comment: Thank you that's a lovely fix. The only alteration I made was just beneath the fadeVisible binding where I have wrapped the whole of the edit area in a binding as follows: "with: (cityToEdit || {})" - this is just so I can contain the null checking to one place and clean up the rest of the bindings. Can you see any issues in doing this? It seems to work well.

Comment: That sounds perfectly reasonable. The main difference is that knockout will redraw the two `input` elements rather than just clearing the values. But since it's only two elements you won't be able to actually notice it :)